# How to bundle circular-dependent modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have two modules: `table.js` and `chart.js`. I would like to bundle them using WebPack, but I end up with an error, probably due to the fact that they are dependent on each other.

`table.js`:

```
var chart = require('./chart');
module.exports = (function () {
    var init = function() {
        _loadTable();
        chart.init();
    };

    var update = function() {
        console.log('table updated');
    };

    return {
        init:   init,
        update: update
    }
})();
```

`chart.js`:

```
var table = require('./table');
module.exports = (function () {
    var init = function() {
        _drawChart();
        table.update(); // will throw an error: table.update is not a function
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
})();
```

What happens here?
Table is loaded first by `table.init()` and then loads chart module by `chart.init()`. Chart is drawed and tries to update the table in return.

However, at this point `chart.js` doesn't know what is `var table = require('./table')` (because at that moment `var table = {}`), thus `table.update()` will throw an error.

This didn't happen before when modules were managed "traditionally" (loaded by script tags and communicated through global `window` object).

I am wondering, if WebPack can still be used for parallely-dependent modules like these?

Comment: I don't know about webpack but if it follows the module resolution process that node does, simply put there's no `update` function on the exported object yet. How did you had it before?

Comment: Actually, I take that back, this must be an issue with WebPack because the module resolution process shouldn't have any problems with this. All you are doing is exporting functions and you aren't calling them until all modules are done being executed.

Answer (score 0):

This article provides a pretty exhaustive list of what you can do to solve your problem.

http://www.bitnative.com/2015/02/03/circular-dependencies-in-requirejs/

The inline form of the requires statement is probably the quickest fix, but has numerous drawbacks.